# Silverlight Componentone flex grid -- merging all the columns in a row

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, componentone, c1flexgrid

I had a requirement while working with silverlight5.0 Component-One flex grid. My requirement is, for a single row i need to merge all the columns.

I have attached the requirement image. please help me..
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please, ask this question in official support forum: http://our.componentone.com/groups/silverlight/flexgrid-for-silverlight/forum/
It's free